# Access attribute from console, js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following script-snippet on a website

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.paper-image').click(function() {
    if(confirm(testResults)) {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('congrats-url');
    }
})
})
```

How do I get the value of `$(this).attr('congrats-url');` from a console in Firefox.

Comment: `$('.paper-image').attr('congrats-url');` if there is only one element with the class `.paper-image`

Answer (score 0):

The snippet might apply to multiple elements in the page.

To display all the `congrat-url` attributes try

```
$('.paper-image').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('congrats-url') );
});
```